# `sudo` equivalent of `sshpass`? `sudopass`?

Tags: password, sudo

The `sshpass` programme can automatically enter the ssh password without you having

Is there anything that will do that for a `sudo` prompt? Like `sudopass`? e.g. `sudopass -p SUDOPASSWORD sudo -i`

Ubuntu Linux 18.04 (or 20.04). *I am aware you can make sudo not require a password, but I am ssh'ing into a server I don't control, and can't do that.*

Comment: Well, there is `sudo -S`, but I guess I don't have to tell you that this isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide an askpass program to sudo by exporting the `SUDO_ASKPASS` environmental variable, and providing the `-A` switch to sudo.

The askpass program must provide the password to its standard output (like `ssh-askpass` normally does). It might worth noting that the content of the `SUDO_ASKPASS` variable must be the path of the executable, as `sudo` tries to run the whole value as is was a program. For this reason, you can't use programs with arguments, you have to write a wrapper script if you want to do so.